# Codename one error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component is already contained in Container

Tags: codenameone

This is the error I get when I run the project :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component is already contained in Container
```

It's  because the decalaration of the `Button`s is outside the `createcell` method but the problem is that if I declare them inside the method the `ActionListener` doesn't work

```
Button eval = new Button("Evaluate");
Button img = new Button("See image");
Object[][] rows = new Object[articles.size()][];
for (int iter = 0;
        iter < rows.length;
        iter++) {
    rows[iter] = new Object[]{
        articles.get(iter).getName(),
        0,
        articles.get(iter).getDescription(),
        articles.get(iter).getLabel(),
        articles.get(iter).getQuantity(),
        articles.get(iter).getRating(), 0
    };
}

TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"name", "description", "Image", "label", "quantity", "rating", "rate"}, rows);
Table table = new Table(model) {
    @Override
    protected Component createCell(Object value, int row, int column, boolean editable) {

        if (row > -1 && column == 2) {
            return img;
        }
        if (row > -1 && column == 6) {
            return eval;
        }
        eval.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Dialog.show("thank you for rating our product ", createStarRankSlider(5), new Command("Cancel"));
            }
        });
        value.toString();
        img.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Dialog.show("HAY LIMAGE", "Insert image here", new Command("Cancel"));
            }
        });
        return super.createCell(value, row, column, editable);
    }
};

add(table);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the same instance of the component instead of creating a new instance. You must always create a component in this method.

E.g. this method is invoked for cell 1,1 of the table. Returns img. Then for 1,2 and again returns img... Since img already has a parent component this will fail.